# access usb from u-boot

Tags: linux, u-boot

I am using u-boot 2013.04 and i have enabled usb support by adding the following in .h file.

```
 /* USB Configs */
  #define CONFIG_CMD_USB
  #define CONFIG_CMD_FAT
  #define CONFIG_USB_EHCI
  #define CONFIG_USB_EHCI_MX6
  #define CONFIG_USB_STORAGE
  #define CONFIG_USB_HOST_ETHER 
  #define CONFIG_USB_ETHER_ASIX
  #define CONFIG_USB_ETHER_SMSC95XX
  #define CONFIG_MXC_USB_PORT     1
  #define CONFIG_MXC_USB_PORTSC   (PORT_PTS_UTMI | PORT_PTS_PTW)
  #define CONFIG_MXC_USB_FLAGS    0
```

I am able to see usb enabled at u-boot with the following prompt

```
  U-Boot > usb start
  (Re)start USB...
  USB0:   USB EHCI 1.00
  scanning bus 0 for devices... 1 USB Device(s) found
   scanning usb for storage devices... 0 Storage Device(s) found
   scanning usb for ethernet devices... 0 Ethernet Device(s) found
```

But there is no blinking of USB and there should have been 1 Storage Device found instead of 0 as seen from the log.

Please help me.

Comment: What's plugged in?  U-Boot can be fussy as to what USB devices it will recognize.  U-Boot has problems detecting one SDcard reader/adapter that I have, but another one and flash drives are okay.  Have you tried different storage devices?

Comment: I have tried USB related KEYBOARD, MOUSE, USB Hard drives. Not SD card reader.

Answer (score 1):

I confirm this issue on U-Boot 2013.01.01. The detection works sometimes but not all the time on Lexar 8G USB stick.

You need to try different brands of USB stick, one for sure will work. I am still searching for one that would work 100% of the time.

I looked at the U-boot fixes and find one recently that may address your problem:
http://git.denx.de/?p=u-boot.git;a=commit;h=dcc7dbc73169bb4e39f27c1d95bbf031ccfc1744

So it is advised to recompile the latest version of U-Boot.